# can someone tell me why this sp takes so much time?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

When executing the below stored procedure it takes 20 mins .The expected time is 2-3 mins.
why this is happening?
can someone tell me why this sp takes so much time?what can be done to make it run faster?
Thanks a lot in advance.The logic of this procedure is ,it checks whether the order number is present in the table if not then inserts into that table

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_load_order
    IS
       l_ds_ds_id               data_source.ds_id%TYPE;
       l_carrier                stage_na_shipment.haulier_name%TYPE;
       l_vehicle_number         stage_na_shipment.haulier_num%TYPE;
       l_ship_date              stage_na_shipment.ship_date`enter code here`%TYPE;
       l_source_key             VARCHAR2 (20);
       l_source_key_1           VARCHAR2 (20);
       l_quantity               stage_na_shipment.quantity%TYPE;
       l_ship_from              stage_na_shipment.ship_from%TYPE;
       l_prod_prod_id           product.prod_prod_id%TYPE;
       l_client                 stage_na_shipment.client%TYPE;
       l_ord_id                 ordr.ord_id%TYPE;
       l_sf_sf_id               ship_from.sf_id%TYPE;
       l_cust_cust_id           customer.cust_cust_id%TYPE;
       l_ord_stat_ord_stat_id   ordr_status.ord_stat_id%TYPE;
       l_le_le_id               legal_entity.le_id%TYPE;
       l_mkt_mkt_id             market.mkt_id%TYPE;
       l_code                   bill_type.code%TYPE;
       l_ord_ord_id             ordr.ord_id%TYPE;
       l_ord_prod_id            ordr_product.ord_prod_id%TYPE;
       l_po_number              stage_na_shipment.po_number%TYPE;
       l_expct_ship_date        stage_na_shipment.ship_date%TYPE;
       l_bt_bt_id               bill_type.bt_id%TYPE;
       l_order_process_date     stage_na_shipment.ship_date%TYPE;
       l_storage_loc            stage_na_shipment.stor_loc%TYPE;
       l_ship_unit_code_8       stage_na_shipment.ship_unit_code_8%TYPE;
       l_del_point              stage_na_shipment.DEL_POINT%type;
       l_r_num                  NUMBER;
       n_1                      NUMBER;
       l_error_msg              VARCHAR2 (500);
       start_time timestamp;
       end_time timestamp;
    BEGIN
    start_time:=systimestamp;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Procedure started' ||start_time);

       sp_log_entry (SYSDATE, 'SP_LOAD_ORDER', 'START', NULL, NULL, NULL);

       start_time:=systimestamp;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('DS_ID start_time' ||start_time);

       SELECT ds_id
        INTO l_ds_ds_id
         FROM data_source
        WHERE ds_id = 1;

       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('DS_ID' || l_ds_ds_id);

        end_time:=systimestamp;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('DS_ID start_time' ||end_time);

       start_time:=systimestamp;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ord_stat_id start_time' ||start_time);

       SELECT ord_stat_id
         INTO l_ord_stat_ord_stat_id
         FROM ordr_status
        WHERE ord_stat_id = 2;

     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ORD_STAT_ID' || l_ord_stat_ord_stat_id);

       end_time:=systimestamp;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ORD_STAT_ID end_time' ||end_time);


     start_time:=systimestamp;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('le_id start_time' ||start_time);

       SELECT le_id
         INTO l_le_le_id
         FROM legal_entity
        WHERE le_id = 1;

       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('LE_ID' || l_le_le_id);
       end_time:=systimestamp;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('LE_ID end_time' ||end_time);

          SELECT COUNT (*)
            INTO l_r_num
            FROM frontroom.ordr;

          sp_log_entry (SYSDATE,
                        'SP_LOAD_ORDER',
                        'MESSAGE',
                        'FRONTROOM_BEF_INS',
                        l_r_num,
                        NULL
                       );

          SELECT COUNT (*)
            INTO l_r_num
            FROM frontroom.ordr_product;

          sp_log_entry (SYSDATE,
                        'SP_LOAD_ORDER',
                        'MESSAGE',
                        'ORDRPRODUCT_BEFORE_INS',
                        l_r_num,
                        NULL
                       );


        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('loop started' ||start_time);

       FOR i IN (SELECT order_num_cos, ship_date, haulier_name, haulier_num,
                        po_number, stor_loc, ship_unit_code, ship_unit_code_8,
                        so_item, ship_from, del_point, currency, client, quantity
                   FROM stage_na_shipment)
       LOOP

          l_source_key := TO_CHAR (i.order_num_cos);
          l_carrier := TO_CHAR (i.haulier_name);
          l_vehicle_number := TO_CHAR (i.haulier_num);
          l_source_key_1 := TO_CHAR (i.order_num_cos || i.so_item);
          l_po_number := i.po_number;
          l_storage_loc := TO_CHAR (i.stor_loc);
          l_del_point :=i.del_point;
          l_ship_date := i.ship_date;
          l_ship_from := TO_CHAR (i.ship_from);
          l_ship_unit_code_8 := TO_CHAR (i.ship_unit_code_8);
          l_client := TO_CHAR (i.client);


          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('order_number' || i.order_num_cos);

          BEGIN
          start_time:=systimestamp;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('mkt_id start_time' ||start_time);

             SELECT mkt_id  INTO l_mkt_mkt_id
               FROM market
              WHERE code =  DECODE (SUBSTR (l_client, 1, 4), 'US23', 'MM',
                                            'US99', 'AFFCO' );

             DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('MKT_ID' || l_mkt_mkt_id);
          EXCEPTION
             WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
             THEN
                sp_log_entry (SYSDATE, 'SP_LOAD_ORDER', NULL,  'THE MKT ID  NOT FOUND  :',
                              NULL, NULL  );
                GOTO end_loop;

                WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
                 sp_log_entry (SYSDATE, 'SP_LOAD_ORDER', NULL,  'MKT ID TWO MANY ROWS  FOUND  :'||i.order_num_cos,
                              NULL, NULL  );

             WHEN others
             THEN
                sp_log_entry (SYSDATE, 'SP_LOAD_ORDER', NULL, SQLERRM, NULL, NULL );
          END;
     end_time:=systimestamp;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('mkt_id end_time' ||end_time);

     start_time:=systimestamp;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('bt_id start_time' ||start_time);


          BEGIN
             IF i.quantity >= 0
             THEN
                l_code := 'O';
             ELSE
                l_code := 'C';
             END IF;

             SELECT bt_id  INTO l_bt_bt_id  FROM bill_type
                        WHERE code = l_code
                         AND ds_ds_id = l_ds_ds_id;

          EXCEPTION
             WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
             THEN
                sp_log_entry
                           (SYSDATE,
                            'SP_LOAD_ORDER',
                            NULL,
                            'BILL TYPE ID NOT FOUND',
                            NULL,
                            NULL
                           );
                           GOTO end_loop;


                         WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
                 sp_log_entry (SYSDATE, 'SP_LOAD_ORDER', NULL,  'BILL TYPE ID TWO MANY ROWS  FOUND  :'||i.order_num_cos,
                              NULL, NULL  );

                           WHEN others
             THEN
                sp_log_entry (SYSDATE,
                              'SP_LOAD_ORDER',
                              NULL,
                              SQLERRM,
                              NULL,
                              NULL
                             );
          END;

          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('BT_ID   :' || l_bt_bt_id);

           end_time:=systimestamp;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('BT_ID end_time' ||end_time);

       start_time:=systimestamp;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('prod_id start_time' ||start_time);

          BEGIN
             SELECT prod_prod_id
               INTO l_prod_prod_id
               FROM product
              WHERE secondary_source_key = LTRIM (l_ship_unit_code_8, 0);
          EXCEPTION
             WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
             THEN
                sp_log_entry (SYSDATE,
                              'SP_LOAD_ORDER',
                              NULL,
                              'THE PRODUCT ID '  ||i.ship_unit_code_8 ||' could not be found in product table :',
                'order_num_cos = ' || i.order_num_cos
                              ,
                              NULL
                             );
                             GOTO end_loop;

                             WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
                 sp_log_entry (SYSDATE, 'SP_LOAD_ORDER', NULL,  'THE PRODUCT ID TWO MANY ROWS  FOUND  :' ||i.order_num_cos,
                              NULL, NULL  );

             WHEN OTHERS
             THEN
                sp_log_entry (SYSDATE,
                              'SP_LOAD_ORDER',
                              NULL,
                              SQLERRM,
                              i.ship_unit_code_8 || SQLERRM,
                              NULL
                             );
          END;

         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' PROD_PROD_ID  :' || l_prod_prod_id);

         end_time:=systimestamp;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('PROD_ID end_time' ||end_time);

          start_time:=systimestamp;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('sf_id start_time' ||start_time);

          BEGIN
             SELECT sf_id
               INTO l_sf_sf_id
               FROM ship_from
              WHERE source_key = l_ship_from;
          EXCEPTION
             WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
             THEN
                sp_log_entry (SYSDATE,
                              'SP_LOAD_ORDER',
                              NULL,
                              'sf_id NOT FOUND',
                              NULL,
                              NULL
                             );
                             GOTO end_loop;

                             WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
                 sp_log_entry (SYSDATE, 'SP_LOAD_ORDER', NULL,  'sf_id TWO MANY ROWS  FOUND  :'||i.order_num_cos,
                              NULL, NULL  );

                             WHEN others
             THEN
                sp_log_entry (SYSDATE,
                              'SP_LOAD_ORDER',
                              NULL,
                              SQLERRM,
                              NULL,
                              NULL
                             );

          END;

         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('SF_ID  :' || l_sf_sf_id);

         end_time:=systimestamp;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('sf_id end_time' ||end_time);

    start_time:=systimestamp;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('cust_id start_time' ||start_time);


          BEGIN
             SELECT cust_id
               INTO l_cust_cust_id
               FROM customer
              WHERE true_gcdb_source_key = to_char(i.del_point);
              -- AND ds_ds_id = l_ds_ds_id;
          EXCEPTION
             WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
             THEN
                sp_log_entry (SYSDATE,
                              'SP_LOAD_ORDER',
                              NULL,
                              'THE CUST ID ' || l_del_point || 'COULD NOT BE FOUND IN THE CUSTOMER TABLE''order_num_cos = '||i.order_num_cos,
                              NULL,
                              NULL
                             );
                             GOTO end_loop;


                             WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
                 sp_log_entry (SYSDATE, 'SP_LOAD_ORDER', NULL,  'cust_id TWO MANY ROWS  FOUND  :'||i.order_num_cos,
                              NULL, NULL  );

            WHEN others
             THEN
                sp_log_entry (SYSDATE,
                              'SP_LOAD_ORDER',
                              NULL,
                              SQLERRM,
                              NULL,
                              NULL
                             );
          END;

         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('CUST_ID  :' || l_cust_cust_id);

         end_time:=systimestamp;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('CUST_ID end_time' ||end_time);

    start_time:=systimestamp;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('INSERTING INTO frontroom.ordr' ||start_time);

          BEGIN
             INSERT INTO frontroom.ordr
                         (ord_number, ds_ds_id, erlst_ship_dt, carrier,
                          vehicle_number, ord_dt, source_key, sf_sf_id,
                          cust_cust_id, ord_stat_ord_stat_id, le_le_id,
                          mkt_mkt_id, sc_sc_id, ctrl_dt, po_number,
                          expct_ship_date, bt_bt_id, order_process_dt,
                          storage_loc)
                SELECT l_source_key, l_ds_ds_id, i.ship_date, l_carrier,
                       l_vehicle_number, i.ship_date, l_source_key, l_sf_sf_id,
                       l_cust_cust_id, l_ord_stat_ord_stat_id, l_le_le_id,
                       l_mkt_mkt_id, 0, i.ship_date, l_po_number, i.ship_date,
                       l_bt_bt_id, i.ship_date, l_storage_loc
                  FROM DUAL
                 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1--ord_number
                                     FROM frontroom.ordr
                                    WHERE ord_number = l_source_key);

          EXCEPTION
             WHEN OTHERS
             THEN
                l_error_msg := SQLERRM;
                sp_log_entry (SYSDATE,
                              'SP_LOAD_ORDER',
                              NULL,
                              l_error_msg,
                             'order_num_cos = ' || i.order_num_cos,
                              NULL
                             );
                             GOTO end_loop;
          END;

         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Inserted into order table');

          end_time:=systimestamp;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Inserted into order table' ||end_time);



          SELECT ord_id
            INTO l_ord_ord_id
            FROM frontroom.ordr
           WHERE ord_number = l_source_key;


    start_time:=systimestamp;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('INSERTING INTO frontroom.ordr_product' ||start_time);

          BEGIN
             INSERT INTO ordr_product
                         (volume, revenue, source_key, ord_ord_id, prod_prod_id,
                          local_currency)
                SELECT i.ship_unit_code, 0, l_source_key_1, l_ord_ord_id,
                       l_prod_prod_id, i.currency
                  FROM DUAL
                 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                             SELECT 1--ord_ord_id
                               FROM ordr_product
                              WHERE ord_ord_id =
                                               (SELECT ord_id
                                                  FROM ordr
                                                 WHERE ord_number = l_source_key));

          EXCEPTION
             WHEN OTHERS
             THEN
                l_error_msg := SQLERRM;
                sp_log_entry (SYSDATE,
                              'SP_LOAD_ORDER',
                              NULL,
                              l_error_msg,
                             'order_num_cos = ' || i.order_num_cos,
                              NULL
                             );
                             GOTO end_loop;
          END;

          n_1 := n_1 + 1;
          if n_1 = 100 then
                   COMMIT;
                    n_1 :=  0;
          end if;

          <<end_loop>>
          null;


       END LOOP;
         end_time:=systimestamp;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Inserted into order table' ||end_time);


        end_time:=systimestamp;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Loop ends' ||end_time);

          SELECT COUNT (*)
            INTO l_r_num
            FROM frontroom.ordr;

          sp_log_entry (SYSDATE,
                        'SP_LOAD_ORDER',
                        'MESSAGE',
                        'FRONTROOM_AFTER_INS',
                        l_r_num,
                        NULL
                       );

       SELECT COUNT (*)
         INTO l_r_num
         FROM frontroom.ordr_product;

       sp_log_entry (SYSDATE,
                     'SP_LOAD_ORDER',
                     'MESSAGE',
                     'ORDRPRODUCT_AFTER_INS',
                     l_r_num,
                     NULL
                    );
       sp_log_entry (SYSDATE, 'SP_LOAD_ORDER', 'COMPLETE', NULL, NULL, NULL);

         end_time:=systimestamp;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Procedure ends' ||end_time);

       COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS
       THEN
          l_error_msg := SQLERRM;
          sp_log_entry (SYSDATE, 'SP_LOAD_ORDER', NULL, l_error_msg, NULL, NULL);
    END sp_load_order;
    /
```

Comment: The procedure is rather lengthy. Which SQL in the procedure is taking most time?

Answer (score 2):

Luckily you're using PL/SQL Developer, which makes PL/SQL Profiling extremely easy.

1. Open up a Test Window, File-->New-->Test Window.
2. Add `sp_load_order;` to the middle.
3. Click on the gauge icon at the top to enable profiling.
4. Run the procedure by hitting F8 or the run button.  Wait for it to finish.
5. Click on the Profiler tab.
6. Click on the column "Total time" to sort descending.

Then you will know exactly which lines of the procedure are slow.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the database, it's quite hard to figure out what the problem is, especially with a quite large procedure like this one.

There are however a few things you could think about:

You're doing DML (inserts) in a loop, often you can gain quite a performance improvement by using bulk operations. for more info, have a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/tuning.htm#i48876
A more "user friendly" description can be found here:http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/bulk-binds-and-record-processing-9i.php
Beware that if you're unfamiliar with bulk operations, it can be a tough nut to crack at first.

Before doing anything drastic (the problem could be as simple as a missing index) you could analyze the problem by tracing it first.

To do that, you first have to start te procedure, and figure out it's session id and serial# by using this query (from another session):

```
select username, status, sid, serial# from v$session
```

once you got that, you can start the trace with this command:

```
exec dbms_monitor.session_trace_enable(session_id=>3,serial_num=>5027,binds=>true,waits=>true);
```

as soon as the procedure is finished, you can stop the trace:

```
exec dbms_monitor.session_trace_disable(session_id=>3,serial_num=>5027);
```

Oracle will now have written some trace files, to figure out where oracle has placed them, execute this command:

```
SELECT VALUE FROM V$DIAG_INFO WHERE NAME = 'Default Trace File';
```

The tracefile is not very readably, but you can get a readable report with the tkprof command line utility. You can run if from the command line like this:

```
tkprof <source trace file> <output file>
```

You will now have a file with all queries that have been run in it, and per report a table like this in it:

```
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        9      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      9      0.00       0.01          1         32          0           1
Fetch        3      0.00       0.00          0         32          0           1
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total       21      0.00       0.01          1         64          0           2
```

This way you can possibly figure out what query is taking the longest.
You will also get info like this from it, wich can tell you the number of queries that have been run:

```
1  session in tracefile.
9  user  SQL statements in trace file.
2  internal SQL statements in trace file.
11  SQL statements in trace file.
10  unique SQL statements in trace file.
504  lines in trace file.
4  elapsed seconds in trace file.
```

p.s. all tracing samples are courtesy of http://tinky2jed.wordpress.com/technical-stuff/oracle-stuff/what-is-the-correct-way-to-trace-a-session-in-oracle/